# Inserting an Array in shared-preferences

Tags: android, arrays, json

Hey guy's i have an app that im doing that loads Android Tv view for Movies.

i have a site that contains all the information in my Database for Login and  content.

so in leanback the categories are already defined with :

```
public static final String MOVIE_CATEGORY[] = {
        "Category Zero",
        "Category One",
        "Category Two",
        "Category Three",
        "Category Four",
        "Category Five",
};
```

But i want to grab the information from my database.

so in main i created AsyncHttpTask task and parsing my response, my goal is to insert the categories in my shared preferences and retrieve it from the MOVIE_CATEGORY.

i just need the id and name

```
   private void parseResult(String result) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id       = jsonobject.getString("CID");
                String name    = jsonobject.getString("name");

 //Log.e("TAG","This is the results" + " ID "+ id + " Name "+name);
                iD = new String[]{id};
                catName=new String[]{name};
                editor.putString("id" + i, iD[i] + "name"+ catName[i] );
                editor.apply();
      Log.e("TAG","This is the results"  + Arrays.deepToString(iD));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but i get this

key: id0       value :6name2018

my json response looks like this :

```
    [{"CID":6,"name":"2018","image":"https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/zTF913m8jVc\/maxresdefault.jpg"},
{"CID":7,"name":"2017","image":"http:\/\/mtltimes.ca\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/12\/Best-movies-2017-493x300.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not save array directly into the shared preferences. But you can save json string and retrieve it when you need and then convert it back to array using Gson().
Here is the library which allows you to simply convert json object to custom class object and json string to objects.
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/README.md

Comment: ok i will store it as is but the i need to retrieve it and parse it again. isn't it redundant?can i parse it first get the name and id and store only that?

Comment: @Deepak you can save `Set<String>` using `putStringSet`

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Set a set of String values in the preferences editor, to be written
     * back once {@link #commit} or {@link #apply} is called.
     * 
     * @param key The name of the preference to modify.
     * @param values The set of new values for the preference.  Passing {@code null}
     *    for this argument is equivalent to calling {@link #remove(String)} with
     *    this key.
     * @return Returns a reference to the same Editor object, so you can
     * chain put calls together.
     */
    Editor putStringSet(String key, @Nullable Set<String> values);


public static void storeSharedItem(Context ctx, String key, Set<String> stringSet) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.WOK_SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(key, stringSet);
    editor.apply();
}
```